# _.function() version of underscore's _.property() function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Underscore has an Object function _.property(key) which returns a function that itself returns the 'key' property of any passed in object.  For example:

```
var moe = {name: 'moe'};
var propFunction = _.property('name');
var value = propFunction(moe);
=> 'moe'
```

I'm wondering if there's a good way with Underscore to get the same behavior with an object's function in addition to just an object's property.  I'm pretty sure there's not a single function for it, but I'm wondering if there's some reasonable combination of functions that together will do what I want.  For example:

```
var moe = {getName: function() { return 'moe'; }};
var funcFunction = _.underscoreGoodnessHere('getName');
var value = funcFunction(moe);
=> 'moe'
```

This would be to remove some of the boilerplate in some pseudo-real code I have like this:

```
this.collection.filter(function(model) { return model.isHidden(); });
// could change to this:
this.collection.filter(_.underscoreGoodness('isHidden'));
```

For what it's worth, if there is not a great way to do what I've asked but you still have a better way to write my pseudo-real code above, I'd still love to hear that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the callback function that Underscore uses in [`_.invoke()`](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-25) - however that is not public. You can build it easily yourself:

```
_.method = function(name) {
  var args = _.tail(arguments),
      isFunc = _.isFunction(name);
  return function(value) {
    return (isFunc ? name : value[name]).apply(value, args);
  };
};
```

Comment: Shame no good way seems to exist without throwing together my own function.  I like to avoid extending underscore where possible but don't mind doing so occasionally when it's worth it.

This seems like the best implementation of such a function to me since it handles arbitrary additional arguments as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own function which is based on `_.property`:

```
function callProperty(prop) {
    var getProperty = _.property(prop);
    return function(obj) {
        return getProperty(obj)();
    };
}
```

Comment: Using `_.property` seems to be pretty inefficient.

Comment: @Bergi: True. I was just fixated on it because it was mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Bergi: sorry if this is a dumb question, but why do you say _.property is inefficient?  Do you mean that function itself (seems pretty straightforward to me looking at the source), or the later usage of it in the example code above where it just needlessly calls it for each invocation of the result function by the client?

Comment: @Cameron:There is no need to use `_.property`. You could just do `function callProperty(prop) { return function (obj) { return obj[prop](); }; }`. So, you avoid an additional function call, which is of course more efficient.

Comment: Right, so nothing inherently slow about _.property that I wasn't understanding.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

Shortest I can think of is using: `_.result()`

```
function functionProp(prop){
    return function(obj){
        return _.result(obj, prop);
    };
}
```

Which will actually also work for non-function properties. So:

```
var moe = {getName: function() { return this.name; }, name: 'moe'};
'moe' == functionProp('getName')(moe);
'moe' == functionProp('name')(moe);
```

Answer (score 0):

Underscore's `property` function doesn't distinguish between "functional properties" and "regular properties". To it, a function object stored under a property name is the property value itself. Extending the example you provided you see the following:

```
var moe = {getName: function() { return 'moe'; }};
var funcFunction = _.property('getName');
var getter = funcFunction(moe);
=> function() { return 'moe'; }
var value = getter();
=> 'moe'

funcFunction(moe)();
=> 'moe'
```

If you want to build your own, you can do something like the following:

```
function functionalProperty(name) {
    var getter = _.property(name);
    return function (o) { return getter(o); };
}
```

Or, if you want to support both types of properties with the same function, you could do this

```
function anyProperty(name) {
    var getter = _.property(name);
    return function (o) {
        var val = getter(o);
        return _.isFunction(val) ? val() : val;
    };
}
```

Just be careful that you only use this for actual properties and not functions that you didn't really want to get invoked.